# How to get a fixed position textblock on first page of an article?

Tags: header-footer, positioning

I am attempting to create a design for an academic journal in LaTeX. In this, I have been having problems with creating a header that is specific for the first page of each article (etc), and was therefore led to try using a text block that adds relevant information such as title of journal, ISSN, Volume, issue number etc on the first page.

I have however been having problems getting the text block to allign with the header on the subsequent pages, and it seems to me like the text block moves vertically depending on size of title of an article, and whether or not there is an abstract present.

A MWE for a standard article would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,sorting=nyt,cmsdate=both,maxcitenames=2,noibid]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\subsubsectionfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}
  {\bfseries\abstractname}
  {\scshape\abstractname}
  {}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{\textsc{Test Article}}
\author{Name Author\\ 
Affiliation\\
Email}
\date{\nodate}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{81}

\maketitle

\begin{textblock}{10}(0,-4.3)
\noindent \footnotesize{\emph{Journal: The Journal of...} (ISSN NNNN-NNNN)\\
Vol. 11, Nr. 1, (2020), 81--83\\
DOI:  XXXXXXX}
\end{textblock}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead[\thepage]{\textsc{Author}}
\rhead[\textsc{Author}]{\thepage}
\chead{\emph{Journal: The Journal of...}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\begin{abstract}

\noindent \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Keywords}
\begin{abstract}
{\centering Keyword – Keyword – Keyword – Keyword – Keyword
\par
}
\end{abstract}

\subsection*{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Creating this for the first two pages:
[image]

[image]

For editorials and similar texts I then tried to make a slightly amended version of the same file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,sorting=nyt,cmsdate=both,maxcitenames=2,noibid]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\subsubsectionfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}
  {\bfseries\abstractname}
  {\scshape\abstractname}
  {}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{\textsc{Editorial}}
\date{\nodate}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\maketitle

\begin{textblock}{10}(0,-4.3)
\noindent \footnotesize{\emph{Journal: The Journal of...} (ISSN NNNN-NNNN)\\
Vol. 11, Nr. 1, (2020), 1\\
DOI:  XXXXXXX}
\end{textblock}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead[\thepage]{}
\rhead[]{\thepage}
\chead{\emph{Journal: The Journal of...}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\subsection*{}

\lipsum

\bigskip
\bigskip

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc}
Editor & Editor & Editor
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

This however puts the text block in a higher vertical position:

[image]

Is there any way I can get the text block to always be on the same vertical position in every file? Preferably to align with the headers for the subsequent pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd stick with inserting the content in the header rather than trying to position content on the page using something like [`textpos`](//ctan.org/pkg/textpos). Below is an option where you define two different pages styles, one for the first page - `firstpagestyle` - and one for all subsequent pages - `otherpagestyle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage [english]{babel}
%\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\subsubsectionfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}
  {\bfseries\abstractname}
  {\scshape\abstractname}
  {}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
  \fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}}
    \emph{Journal: The Journal of \ldots} (ISSN NNNN-NNNN) \\
    Vol.~11, Nr.~1, (2020), 81--83                     \\
    DOI: XXXXXXX
  \end{tabular}}}
  \fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[C]{\emph{Journal: The Journal of \ldots}}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textsc{Author}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
}

\pagestyle{otherpagestyle}

\title{\textsc{Test Article}}
\author{Name Author\\ 
  Affiliation\\
  Email}
\date{1900-01-01}

\apptocmd{\maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\thispagestyle{firstpagestyle}}% <appendix>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{81}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Keywords}
\begin{abstract}
\centering Keyword -- Keyword -- Keyword -- Keyword -- Keyword
\end{abstract}

\subsection*{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

`firstpagestyle` sets the header using a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular` that has no height (thanks to `\smash`). Subsequent page headers (under `otherpagestyle`) are managed in the usual way.